# Prepare array in linear time to find k smallest elements in O(k)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

This is an interesting question I have found on the web. Given an array containing `n` numbers (with no information about them), we should pre-process the array in linear time so that we can return the `k` smallest elements in *`O(k)`* time, when we are given a number `1 <= k <= n`

I have been discussing this problem with some friends but no one could find a solution; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are those 32-bit numbers, or something like that? In other words, are you allowed to use radix sort?

Comment: its is unknown.you cant use radix sort because it could be non integers.

Comment: are the elements in the array unique?

Comment: Does the resulting elements have to be presented in order?

Comment: Selection followed by partition (as in quicksort) can do the latter step in O(n) time...

Comment: I think the best will be O(n) time and O(k) memory.

Comment: Bill-the element are numbers (integers and not integers).Juan- the order of the elements is not important.Larsmans- its a good point .However the value of k is not known to us in the pre-process time .

Comment: k is unknown to us in the preprocessing stage

Comment: @JuanGuerrero obviously the answer does not have to be presented in order, otherwise the answer for `k = n` would require sorting an array in `O(n)` with no advance information about it whatsoever.

Comment: I don't see how this questions is any different from sorting.

Comment: @idannik I think it's `O(n) ~ Ω(k)` .. check my proposed algorithm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the pre-processing step, we will use the partition-based selection several times on the same data set.

Find the *n/2*-th number with the algorithm.. now the dataset is partitioned into two half, lower and upper. On the lower half find again the middlepoint. On its lower partition do the same thing and so on... Overall this is O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4) + ... = O(n).

Now when you have to return the *k* smallest elements, search for the nearest *x* < *k*, where *x* is a partition boundary. Everything below it can be returned, and from the next partition you have to return *k - x* numbers. Since the next partition's size is *O(k)*, running another selection algorithm for the *k - x* th number will return the rest.

Comment: I think that's quite unintuitive. You're preprocessing earlier elements more, even though you have to retrieve all elements at the same speed. Basically, you're taking advantage of the fact that earlier elements can “pay” for retrieving later elements. For example, if k=n/2+1, getting the first n/2 elements takes ~n/2 time, but getting the last element also takes ~n/2 time. But that's okay, because 2·n/2 is still O(n/2+1).

Comment: hi, should I continue the partition process on the upper half to find again middlepoint and so on ?if not, how do I find the k smallest elements in case that k is larger than n/2?.

Comment: will the selection algorithm in the last sentence work on O(k)?

Comment: 1) no, you only do it for the lower parts. if k is larger than n/2, you return all the elements in the lower partition, plus k-n/2 from the upper part. 2) yes, there are O(k) elements there. Check your last example, that partition has n/2 elements which is smaller than k.

Comment: @svick: I think in a way it's intuitive.. If k is large enough (like in your example, >n/2), you don't even need preprocessing, as the selection algorithm will finish in O(k). As k gets smaller and smaller, there's a bigger need for preprocessing to make sure that you only have to check a handful elements.

Answer (score 1):

We can find the median of a list and partition around it in linear time.

Then we can use the following algorithm: maintain a buffer of size `2k`.

Every time the buffer gets full, we find the median and partition around it, keeping only the lowest `k` elements.
This requires `n/k` find-median-and-partition steps, each of which take `O(k)` time with a traditional quickselect. this approach requires only `O(n)` time.

**Additionally** if you need the sorted output.
Which adds an additional `O(k log k)` time. In total, this approach requires only `O(n + k log k)` time and `O(k)` space.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. what's the preprocessing step here? looks like the whole thing you've described, but that step cannot know about `k`. I don't even understand how this supposed to work.